# Delete Rows - code does works, but not within existing macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the following code to delete empty rows in a worksheet.

```
Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

It works perfectly as a standalone, but when I try to use it in a larger marco, it fails.  Here is the full code:

```
Sub liquidVolume()

    Dim dateTime As String
    Dim MyPath As String

    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Sheets("Volume").Select
    dateTime = Range("i1")


    Sheets("Volume").Select
    Range("A1:E10000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"


    **Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete**
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & dateTime, FileFormat:=xlCSV


End Sub
```

All the code really does is take a worksheet in one workbook, copy the contents into a new workbook's worksheet and formats the date.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the little snippet of code that deletes the row to work.

Comment: Which workbook/sheet are you trying to delete the rows in? As it's set up, it looks like it will delete them in the new workbook.

Comment: You say "it fails". Does it give you an error message? What is that error message?

Comment: Poor wording on my part.  It simply doesn't delete anything.  There is no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was not able to actually delete rows and would like to further understand why formulas are interfering with the deletion of blank rows, I was able to remove the blank rows by sorting the data so that the blank rows are moved to the bottom of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for size. It is not efficient and it only works from version 2010 and newer.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub liquidVolume()
    Dim dateTime As String
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook


    MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    dateTime = Range("i1")

    Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("volume")
    Set rngSource = shtSource.Range("A1:E10000")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set shtTarget = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set rngTarget = shtTarget.Range("A1:E10000")

    rngSource.Copy
    rngTarget.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shtTarget.Columns("B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"
'    Set rngTarget = shtTarget.Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Set rngTarget = EmptyCells(shtTarget.Columns("E:E"))

    If Not rngTarget Is Nothing Then
        rngTarget.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    'wb.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & dateTime, FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub

Public Function EmptyCells(ByVal rngColumn As Range) As Range
    Dim shtSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim rngEmptyCells As Range
    Dim intColumn As Integer

    'Determine the sheet the column belongs to
    Set shtSheet = rngColumn.Parent

    'Determine last used row
    lngLastRow = shtSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row + shtSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

    'Determine column
    intColumn = rngColumn.Columns(1).Column

    'Determine range with empty cells.
    Set rngEmptyCells = Nothing
    For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow
        If Len(Trim(shtSheet.Cells(lngRow, intColumn))) = 0 Then
            If rngEmptyCells Is Nothing Then
                Set rngEmptyCells = shtSheet.Cells(lngRow, intColumn)
            Else
                Set rngEmptyCells = Union(rngEmptyCells, shtSheet.Cells(lngRow, intColumn))
            End If
        End If
    Next lngRow

    Set EmptyCells = rngEmptyCells
End Function
```